# To remove minus sign from the values on the secondary Y-axis (Nvd3 -Multibar Horizontal Chart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, graph, nvd3.js

I want to get rid of the minus sign from the values of the secondary y-axis. 
Below is the graph showing the same.
[Nvd3 Multibar-Horizontal Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTk16.png)

**Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'multiBarHorizontalChart',
            height: 350,
            x: function(d){
                console.log(d.value);
                return d.label;},
            y: function(d){return d.value;},
            //yErr: function(d){ return [-Math.abs(d.value * Math.random() * 0.3), Math.abs(d.value * Math.random() * 0.3)] },
            showControls: true,
            showValues: true,
            duration:"500",
            stacked: true,
            xAxis: {
              showMaxMin: false

            },
            axisLabelDistance:50,
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Values',
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));
                }
            },
            valueFormat:d3.format(".0f"),

        },

    };
```

I have removed the minus sign for the x-axis values, but bot able to remove it from the secondary y-axis. Please help me through this.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to play around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the format of the bars' values much the same like the tick values of the `yAxis` using the `valueFormat` property:

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        /* more lines omitted for brevity */

        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Values',
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));
            }
        },
        valueFormat: function(d){
                return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));
        },

        /* more lines omitted for brevity */
    },

};
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked. Is there a way to align the origin to the center of the page??, as the higher value is making it to shift towards left side.

Comment: @SharathS The centered alignment is more a question of its own. You could do something like `var max = d3.max(chart.yAxis.scale().domain(), function(d) { return Math.abs(d); })); chart.yAxis.scale().domain([-max, max]);`. If you put it in another question, I will post this as an answer to that question.

Comment: @SharathS Why did you revoke the acceptance of this answer? Is it wrong somehow, or doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry! maybe some technical glitch. The answer worked perfectly.